# Change multiple line for loop to Single Line For Loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

This is a way of appending to a list through for loop:

```
lst = [] 
for i in range(5):
    lst.append(i)
```

Though the below may look nicer and better:

```
lst = [i for i in range(5)]
```

I was trying to write the below code same as the second format, but I keep getting error. can anyone help?

```
filtered_list = []
for childList in source_list:
    filtered_childList = remove_emptyElements(childList)    
    if filtered_childList:   
         filtered_list.append(filtered_childList)
```

Comment: While it technically is simple enough to answer your question as is, it would be nice to know what you're trying to do and what your expected output is—that'd help.

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
# one liner as you asked:
filtered_list = [remove_emptyElements(l) for l in source_list if remove_emptyElements(l)]

# but I think that this will be better:
filtered_list = (remove_emptyElements(l) for l in source_list)
filtered_list = [l for l in filtered_list if l]
```

**Update:**
To solve your issue from the comments you can use this code snippet:

```
sequences_result = []
for sequence in sequences:
    for itemset in sequence:
        itemset_result = []
        for item in itemset.split(","):
            itemset_result.append(item.strip())
        sequences_result.append(itemset_result)
print(sequences_result)
```

Comment: Version 2 is definitely better. It avoids the extra call to `remove_emptyElements` and technically speaking calling `remove_emptyElements` could have side effects that result in a different `filtered_list` when using the oneliner.

Comment: @timgeb yes I agree with you. And I think that the lists comprehensions it's not the best solution for the current problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. It exactly works as it was intended. I've got trouble reverting below one line loof to multiple lines loof. here is the original code:

sequences = [[[item.strip() for item in itemset.split(",")] for itemset in sequence] for sequence in sequences]
Multiple line loof that I tried:

  for sequence in sequences:
     for itemset in sequence:
        for item in itemset.split(","):
           sequences.append(item.strip())
It does not work as the original one. Any idea?

Comment: @Mahhos I added an example